# React, Redux-Saga: Which is the best way to handle error in saga and inform component to display that error

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-redux, redux-saga

I got two methods to handle this problem

1) Update error flag in redux and use in the component

2) Use Promise to dispatch the action and then resolve or reject the promise from the saga, so we can use in the component
Ex:

```
doSomething: payload => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dispatch(SomeActions.doSomething(payload, resolve, reject));
      });
    }
```

Which solution should I use, so that I can maintain the code in a proper manner.

If there is any better solution which I can use, please help me to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick with the first approach. According to the redux principles actions are plain objects. That means that passing functions in actions (e.g. resolve and reject to invoke in saga) is considered bad practice.